# How to get list of results configured in struts.xml file, in execute method for that particular Action in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I'm doing struts migration from Struts1 to Struts2 and would like to re-write below code for struts2.

In  the below code we are finding the list of forward available using findForward method. So, i want to know how i could achieve this in struts2

```
ActionForward af = mapping.findForward(mainCode + "." + offset);
if (af != null)
{
    return af;
}
else
{    // need some default place to go
    if(tmp != null && "1".equals(tmp)){
        return new ActionForward("/" + mainCode + ".fixedoffset1");
    }else{
        return new ActionForward("/" + mainCode + ".fixedoffset2");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve with that?

Comment: If you see... i'm trying to check for a combination of an offset with maincode, it is there i'm forwarding the request to it, else i'm redirecting to different location....

Comment: Do you have mapping for every offset? Can you show your action configuration for that?

Comment: In struts1 i dont have such configuration... It will helpful if you can tell me how i can redirect the control from execute method in struts2 like the way ActionForward is being used in the above code.

Comment: You can use `redirectAction` result to redirect to some action or `redirect` to redirect to some url.

Comment: Use a dynamic result, although the use case for what you're doing here eludes me.

Comment: Dave, But, it should be on a conditional basis. Please see the above code, we doing it as, if a result is available to that, else use dynamic result. But, my question is how do you check is a result is available or not for that action mapping, in struts2?